# How can MARS produce weird constants in terms?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, regression

I've been reading about an interesting machine learning algorithm, [MARS(Multi-variate adaptive regression splines).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines)

As far as I understand the algorithm, from Wikipedia and Friedman's papers, it works in two stages, forward pass and backward pass. I'll ignore backward pass for now, since forward pass is the part I'm interested in. The steps for forward pass, as far as I can tell are.

1. Start with just the mean of the data.
2. Generate a new term pair, through exhaustive search
3. Repeat 2 while improvements are being made

And to generate a term pair MARS appears to do the following:

1. Select an existing term (e)
2. Select a variable (x)
3. Select a value of that variable (v)
4. Return two terms one of the form `e*max(0,x-v)` and the other of the form `e*max(0, v-x)`

And this makes sense to me. I could see how, for example, a data table like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | Z |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

Could produce a terms like `2*max(0, B-1)` or even `8*max(0, B-1)*max(3-A)`. However, the wikipedia page has an example that I don't understand. It has an ozone example where the first term is 25. However, it also has term in the final regression that has a coefficient that is negative and fractional. I don't see how this is possible, since the initial term is 5, and you can only multiply by previous terms, and no previous term can have a negative coefficient, that you could ever end up with one...

What am I missing?

As I see it, either I misunderstand term generation, or I misunderstand the simplification process. However, simplification as described seems to only delete terms, not modify them. Can you see what I am missing here?

Comment: Pairs of hinge functions are being added, and one of the pair is mirrored.

Comment: @CS Well aware, and I think that is made fairly clear in the "term pair" section. However, if you want to edit in clarify, feel free! :)

Comment: @CS Unless you meant that the mirroring has some effect on the coefficient, which I don't believe is the case...

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia article, it gives this picture as an example of such a pair of hinge functions:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Friedmans_mars_simple_model.png  If you think about it, since each hinge function is positive-valued, the only way to create such a kinky line is to make one of the hinge functions have a negative coefficient.

Comment: @CS ah, that sorta makes sense... However, how does that explain fractional coefficients?

Comment: Ok, so glancing through the Wikipedia some more, it's kinda vague.  A clearer explanation is in Hastie et al's Elements of Statistical Learning (free pdf).  When you "add a pair", what happens is you pick a basis function in your current model set, and multiply it with a pair of mirrored hinges.  If you picked the constant in your current model set, you just have a pair of mirrored hinges.  BUT, you now have to pick a pair of coefficients too, and these are estimated, along with all the other coefficients from your model set, by least squares.  So you can negative, fractional, etc.

Comment: @CS Wow, thank you so much for the help. That pdf looks great! I'd recommend typing that out as an answer, so that it can be accepted :D

Comment: @CS Not the pdf obviously... But if you do copy paste your comments into an answer, I will accept it :P